# Stripe subscriptions and ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, stripe-payments

I have had no luck whatsoever finding any example code for ASP.NET Web Forms that I can use to let customers sign up for subscriptions.  It has been a long while since I've used Stripe, and all references to Web Forms implementations are gone from their docs.
I contacted their support people and still get pointed to using the .NET smaples that implement MVC, but I'm not doing an MVC-based site and have no desire to learn MVC simply to decipher and port the samples over for a Web Forms project.

Does ANYONE have a sample of code for a Web Forms project page (and code-behind) that lets someone sign up for a Stripe subscription???  I have code for a webhook, but how to do this for the web page is proving to be problematic.

Thanks for any help you can give, guys!

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, StripePayment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/Subscriptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific example for that, but there are a couple of 'Stripe with Webforms' videos that might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGpMRtdxvmQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DDNgYxLHvU

Comment: thank you for that.  I watched those videos yesterday, and they're great if you're processing onetime payments for purchases, but they don't help when it comes to subscription sales, and that's what I'm after.  I chatted with Stripe support, but for whatever reason they don't, can't or won't provide the "legacy" docs that pertain to web forms development.  This is driving me nutty!

Comment: There are no 'legacy docs' for WebForms - it just uses the .NET library.  It's more a question of how you structure things.  Unfortunately all of the languages we have libraries for use some type of routing within a single file to accomplish all the steps, so there's not even really an 'action-per-file' example I can point you to.  If you can make each step shown in the examples be its own WebForms file, I believe it'll work - but I'm not really up on WebForms, so it's a bit of a guess.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I will just use my card processor's API instead. I was hoping for a set of older documentation Stripe had that covered this.  I accepted your answer since you made the effort.  Thanx!